# Inno Setup tmp blocked

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I created an exe file using the Inno Setup and when I going execute it the Avast opens a popup for analyze a file tmp that is generated. I wish Avast would not open it. My exe file is signing with certificate and Windows 's UAC identifies it correctly. Someone can help me?

Comment: There's nothing you can do about this; your installer cannot disable Avast's scanning. (If it could, any malware could do so also and get past the virus scanner.) The user installing your application can temporarily disable Avast before running the install if they wish, or can just wait for Avast to finish scanning and allow the installation to continue.

Comment: How did you sign the installer? Did you use the Inno Setup signing features? Or did you sign it manually yourself?

Comment: I created a .bat file and used the signtool of the Microsoft. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f "mycert.pfx" /p minha_senha /t meu_timestamp "app.exe"

Comment: @KenWhite I don't want disable the Avast, I want know why Avast scanning my .exe file even with the signature and if there is a way of disable the tmp of the inno setup or sign the temp or other thing that can I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted the command to sign my code in the inno setup and now it is signing all files that it creates. But the Avast still are blocking my executable and I think that is because of my code and my certificate reputation that I read in this post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/03/22/everything-you-need-to-know-about-authenticode-code-signing/

I´ll send the setup to Avast analyze and put it in the white list.

Comment: What was the command you put in the inno script to get it to sign the created "tmp" files?